# Оптимизация запроса

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть форум на SMF 1.1.19
При попытке забанить падает на этом запросе:

```
SELECT mem.ID_MEMBER, mem.is_activated + 10 AS new_value
    FROM (smf_ban_groups AS bg, smf_ban_items AS bi, smf_members AS mem)
    WHERE bg.ID_BAN_GROUP = bi.ID_BAN_GROUP
        AND bg.cannot_access = 1
        AND (bg.expire_time IS NULL OR bg.expire_time > " . time() . ")
        AND (mem.ID_MEMBER = bi.ID_MEMBER OR mem.emailAddress LIKE bi.email_address)
        AND mem.is_activated < 10
```

EXPLAIN запроса: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQT0g.png
Индексы таблицы smf_ban_items: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKSXC.png
Индексы таблицы smf_members: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLFoj.png

В таблице members 732.000 записей.
Что можно придумать?

Comment: В некоторых случаях join работает быстрее чем перечисление таблиц в from. Посмотрите explain запроса с join и попробуйте выполнить его.

Comment: избавиться от `OR` и по возможности от `like`. и да переписать через join'ы.